# What is causing ImportError: No module named pkg_resources after upgrade of Python on os X?

Tags: python, ipython

I just updated Python to 2.6.4 on my Mac. 
I installed from the dmg package.

The binary did not seem to correctly set my Python path, so I added `'/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages'` in `.bash_profile`

```
>>> pprint.pprint(sys.path)  
['',
'/Users/Bryan/work/django-trunk', 
'/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages',  
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip',  
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6',  
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin',  
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac',  
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',  
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',  
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old',  
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',  
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
```

Apparently that is not all the required paths because I can't run iPython.

```
$ ipython  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>  
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point  
ImportError: No module named `pkg_resources`
```

I've done Google searches and I can't really figure out how to install `pkg_resources` or make sure it's on the path.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[UPDATE] TL;DR `pkg_resources` is provided by either [Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/) or [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/).

[UPDATE 2] As announced at PyCon 2013, the `Distribute` and `setuptools` projects have re-merged.  `Distribute` is now deprecated and you should just use the new current `setuptools`.   Try this:

```
curl -O https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py
python ez_setup.py
```

Or, better, use a current [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) as the high level interface and which will use `setuptools` under the covers.

[Longer answer for OP's specific problem]:

You don't say in your question but I'm assuming you upgraded from the Apple-supplied Python (2.5 on 10.5 or 2.6.1 on 10.6) or that you upgraded from a python.org Python 2.5.  In any of those cases, the important point is that each Python instance has its own library, including its own site-packages library, which is where additional packages are installed. (And none of them use `/usr/local/lib` by default, by the way.) That means you'll need to install those additional packages you need for your new python 2.6.  The easiest way to do this is to first ensure that the new python2.6 appears first on your search `$PATH` (that is, typing `python2.6` invokes it as expected); the python2.6 installer should have modified your `.bash_profile` to put its framework bin directory at the front of `$PATH`.  Then install `easy_install` using [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/) following the instructions there.  The `pkg_resources` module is also automatically installed by this step.

Then use the newly-installed version of `easy_install` (or `pip`) to install `ipython`.

```
easy_install ipython
```

or

```
pip install ipython
```

It should automatically get installed to the correct `site-packages` location for that python instance and you should be good to go.

Comment: I messed up when I tried to install setuptools last night.
I neglected to finish the installation by running the .egg file as if it were a shell file.

$ sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg

I guess that added the new Python path somewhere.

Comment: NOTE: The actual answer that resolved this issue for me was below- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10538341/293064

Comment: I've updated this old answer a bit to make it more obvious that the solution is to either install `Distribute` or `setuptools`.  The specific steps were in the links.  The OP's question covered other items.

Comment: A further edit to reflect the deprecation of `distribute` in favor of the new `setuptools` and to mention `pip`.

Comment: getting ```python ez_setup.py
  File "ez_setup.py", line 1
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax``` :(

Answer (score 76):

I encountered the same `ImportError`. Somehow the `setuptools` package had been deleted in my Python environment.

To fix the issue, run the setup script for `setuptools`:

```
curl https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py | python
```

If you have any version of [`distribute`](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/merge-faq.html), or any `setuptools` below 0.6, you will have to uninstall it first.*

See [Installation Instructions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.9.8#installation-instructions) for further details.

---

* If you already have a working `distribute`, upgrading it to the "compatibility wrapper" that switches you over to `setuptools` is easier. But if things are already broken, don't try that.

Comment: This is the right way to do it.  Without pkg_resources, `easy_install` will likely also not work (so `easy_install` and `pip` won't be able to install setuptools).

Comment: Installing Distribute or setuptools is, in fact, what the accepted answer recommended.  I've updated the original answer a bit to make it more obvious.  BTW, it is somewhat dangerous to download and install something from an insecure URL like that without examining the contents of the file first.

Answer (score 7):

In case of upgrading your python on mac os 10.7 and pkg_resources doesn't work, the simplest way to fix this is just reinstall setuptools as Ned mentioned above.

```
sudo pip install setuptools --upgrade
or sudo easy_install install setuptools --upgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

On my system (OSX 10.6) that package is at

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py
```

I hope that helps you figure out if it's missing or just not on your path.

Answer (score 1):

The reason might be because the IPython module is not in your PYTHONPATH.

If you donwload IPython and then do 
 python setup.py install

The setup doesn't add the module IPython to your python path. 
You might want to add it to your PYTHONPATH manually. It should work after you do :

export PYTHONPATH=/pathtoIPython:$PYTHONPATH

Add this line in your .bashrc or .profile to make it permanent.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is not related to OSX, but on an embedded system (Beagle Bone Angstrom) I had the exact same error message. Installing the following ipk packages solved it.

```
opkg install python-setuptools
opkg install python-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on **Ubuntu**, and the following worked for me:

Removed the dropbox binaries and download them again, by running:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist
dropbox start -i
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with the same problem when i am working on autobahn related project.

1)    So I download the setuptools.-0.9.8.tar.gz form https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/ and extract it.

2    )Then i get the pkg_resources module and copy it to the folder where it needed. 
**in my case that folder was C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\autobahn

Answer (score 0):

In my case, package `python-pygments` was missed. You can fix it by command:

`sudo apt-get install python-pygments`

If there is problem with `pandoc`. You should install `pandoc` and `pandoc-citeproc`.

`sudo apt-get install pandoc pandoc-citeproc`

Answer (score 0):

Try this only if you are ok with uninstalling python.

I uninstalled python using

```
brew uninstall python
```

then later installed using

```
brew install python
```

then it worked!