# scikits statsmodels - ImportError

Tags: python, importerror, scikits, statsmodels

How can I troubleshoot this import error? Thanks.

```
    import scikits.statsmodels.api as sm
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scikits\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is causing ImportError: No module named pkg_resources after upgrade of Python on os X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756721/what-is-causing-importerror-no-module-named-pkg-resources-after-upgrade-of-pyth)

Comment: @eumiro I have setuptools installed, which seemed to be the issue in post you referenced.

Comment: ok, then ignore my comment please.

Comment: Are you sure you have setuptools installed on the python interpreter installed in `C:\Python27`? Have you tried to do a:
`import pkg_resources`?

Comment: Okay, I should have tried that first. The import failed. I guess I didn't install setuptools properly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same `ImportError`. Somehow the `setuptools` package had been deleted in my Python environment.

To fix the issue, run the setup script for `setuptools`:

```
curl https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py | python
```

If you have any version of [`distribute`](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/merge-faq.html), or any `setuptools` below 0.6, you will have to uninstall it first.*

See [Installation Instructions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.9.8#installation-instructions) for further details.

---

* If you already have a working `distribute`, upgrading it to the "compatibility wrapper" that switches you over to `setuptools` is easier. But if things are already broken, don't try that.

Comment: I should point out that I edited the answer based on [abarnert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert)'s [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources/10538412#comment26822010_10538412).