# Why can't `virtualenv` find `pkg_resources`?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pkg-resources, python-wheel

I'm trying to use virtualenv in Ubuntu to install a local virtual Python environment.  When I run the shell command:

```
$ virtualenv ./virt_python
```

It throws an exception that it can't import `pkg_resources`.  But when I open a Python shell and `from pkg_resources import load_entry_point` it runs fine.  For reference, the complete stacktrace is below.

```
$ virtualenv ./virt_python
New python executable in ./virt_python/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip.......
  Complete output from command /home/rpsharp/local/...hon/bin/easy_install /usr/local/lib/pytho...pport/pip-1.1.tar.gz:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rpsharp/local/workspace/invest-natcap.invest-3/virt_python/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
----------------------------------------
...Installing pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.7.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 928, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1042, in create_environment
    install_pip(py_executable, search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 640, in install_pip
    filter_stdout=_filter_setup)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1006, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/rpsharp/local/...hon/bin/easy_install /usr/local/lib/pytho...pport/pip-1.1.tar.gz failed with error code 1
```

I tried the solution proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10538412/42897 but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: See

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756721/what-is-causing-importerror-no-module-named-pkg-resources-after-upgrade-of-pyth

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem when trying to run virtualenv, found out the virtualenv was installed in  /home/{user}/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages while the python was pointing to /home/{user}/install/bin/virtualenv - you should know this by running

```
which virtualenv
```

So I had to uninstall and reinstall virtualenv

```
pip uninstall virtualenv 
pip install virtualenv
```

This worked for me.

Comment: My virtualenv gave a different error, "can't find pip", but with the same "cannot find wheel for..." symptom, and your solution worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that recent versions never download neither setuptools (distribute) nor pip and expect to find their wheels locally.
Usually virtualenv says something like

```
Cannot find a wheel for setuptools
Cannot find a wheel for pip
```

and fails with the ImportError after that. This is [documented](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html#the-extra-search-dir-option):

> If no satisfactory local distributions are found, virtualenv will fail. Virtualenv will never download packages.

You may want to check if you have **`VIRTUALENV_EXTRA_SEARCH_DIR`** set in your environment or the corresponding option in virtualenv's [config file](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/reference.html#configuration-file) and disable this.

To find out where virtualenv actually searches for the packages you can temporarily add either print statements in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py` or somethig like `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. The function in question is `find_wheels` and you make it look something like this:

```
def find_wheels(projects, search_dirs):
    # … skipping docstring and comments
    for project in projects:
        for dirname in search_dirs:
            print '*** search_dir:', dirname
            files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dirname, project + '-*.whl'))
            if files:
                wheels.append(os.path.abspath(files[0]))
                break
        else:
            logger.fatal('Cannot find a wheel for %s' % (project,))

    return wheels
```

Comment: "just place the corresponding .whl files downloaded from PyPI"

Where does one find the pip*.whl and setuptools*.whl files @ PyPI? Apologies if this is a LMGTFY, but I'm not finding the links ...

Comment: @TomRoche There‘s a table at the bottom of every [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/) [page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip). Direct links: https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-1.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=f20bc8f31e322375ce06b26d73ce7b4f https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/s/setuptools/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=fa55df9cab63a418d155a8b97ef7426e

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the current version of virtualenv. As answered  by [user2676043](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2676043/user2676043) in the same thread, virtualenv is installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. So run the following command:

   `$ python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py --version`

It will return you the version of virtualenv installed on system.

2. Now, change the executable file.

   `$ vim /usr/local/bin/virtualenv`

Change the version to the one received above. Save the file and it works smoothly.