# IPython won't launch after install

Tags: python, ipython

Just got a fresh 64bit box running windows vista, installed Python 2.7.3 and IPython 0.12.1, but IPython didn't seem to create any program folders.

Even if I run the .exe file from C:\Python27\Scripts, the terminal just flashes for a moment.

Any thoughts?

Comment: check your system log for errors and post any that are related to your python.exe file name in your question please it will help the rest of us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when there is an error, it shows error message and get out. That is why you are seeing the flash.

Run the executable from command line and you can check out what that error is.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out the error I was getting is being addressed at another question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756721/what-is-causing-importerror-no-module-named-pkg-resources-after-upgrade-of-pyth

Comment: @Chris: Cool. At least know you will be able to find out the error yourself. I was tripped by it to when I used to click the batch file to only see the flash and nothing happen later on.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a common problem - you need to install [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#installation-instructions) before installing IPython. We don't know how to add it to the start menu without that.